# Parsing sdf file in bash

Tags: linux, bash, parsing, sdf

I found this code for parsing a sdf file but I cannot ignore the whitespace that's why Ki (nm) output does not show.

My file look like this:

---

```
> <Ligand InChI Key>
CPZBLNMUGSZIPR-NVXWUHKLSA-N

> <BindingDB MonomerID>
50417287

> <BindingDB Ligand Name>
Aloxi::Aurothioglucose::PALONOSETRON::PALONOSETRON HYDROCHLORIDE

> <Target Name Assigned by Curator or DataSource>
5-hydroxytryptamine receptor 3A

> <Target Source Organism According to Curator or DataSource>
Homo sapiens

> <Ki (nM)>
 0.0316

> <IC50 (nM)>


> <Kd (nM)>


> <EC50 (nM)>
---------------------------
```

```
awk -v  OFS='\t' '
    /^>/ { tag=$2; next }
    NF { f[tag]=$1 }
    $0 == "$$$$" {print f["<pH>"], f["<PMID>"], f["<Ki (nM)>"] }
' P46098.sdf
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try `match()` function to extract the tag between `<` and `>` inclusive.

```
awk -v  OFS='\t' '
    /^>/ { match($0, /<.+>/); tag = substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH); next }
    NF { f[tag]=$1 }
    $0 == "$$$$" {print f["<pH>"], f["<PMID>"], f["<Ki (nM)>"] }
' P46098.sdf
```

- The function `match($0, /<.+>/)` returns a non-zero value if the regex `<.+>`
  matches `$0` assigning awk variables `RSTART` and  `RLENGTH`
  to the start position and the length of the matched substring.
- The regex `<.+>` matches a substring which starts with `<` and ends with `>`.
  The substring *may* contain whitespace characters.
- `substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)` returns the substring of `$0` starting
  at `RSTART` and length of `RLENGTH` characters. Then the variable
  `tag` is assigned to it.